# Understanding crossfilter.js bit-twiddling hack

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, crossfilter

I found it on crossfilter.js [description](http://square.github.io/crossfilter/) and am trying to understand what this line means

> Crossfilter uses sorted indexes (and a few bit-twiddling hacks) to
>   make this possible, dramatically increasing the perfor­mance of live
>   histograms and top-K lists.

The sorted-index refers to the use of index like in databases, I think. To avoid doing full-table scans. Each dimension has an index on which filtering is done. This leads to incremental filtering (filter each index one by one) and finally when filtered data is finally generated, events are fired.

But looking at the [code](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/blob/master/src/crossfilter.js#L81) I could not understand what the hack is, what is it used for and how. Can anyone explain the purpose of bit-twiddling here ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the beginning there's this declaration:

`m = 0, // a bit mask representing which dimensions are in use`

A "bit mask" is a simple and efficient way to keep track of a list of true/false options. Let's say you create a listing of cars for sale and you want to set four extra parameters of each car listed: 4x4, ABS, ESP, climatronic. You could define a car object like this:

```
MyCar = { brand : "Mercedes", 
          extras : {
              "4x4" : false,
              "ABS" : true,
              "ESP" : false,
              "climatronic" : true
          }
        }
```

These extras are easy to set and retrieve: `if( MyCar.extras['4x4'] ){ /* display a ✓ */ }`. It's easy, simple, readable but in some cases may require too many resources to process (think: nested loops over a huge collection).

So we may create an array where each index corresponds to a feature, right?

```
MyCar = {  brand : "Mercedes",
           // 1: 4x4, 2: ABS, 3: ESP, 4: climatronic
           extras : [ false, true, false, true ]
        }
```

Now to check whether given car has 4x4 you need to use `if( MyCar.extras[0] ){ /* display a ✓ */ }`. It's less readable (you need to consult documentation to know which feature is under which index) but probably faster an requires less memory.

The concept of a bitmask is similar, but uses numbers instead of arrays. `extras : [ false, true, false, true ]` could be shortened to `extras : [ 0, 1, 0, 1 ]` and `0101` is a binary representation of the number `5`. So a Car object with a bitmask describing its features could look like this:

```
MyCar = {  brand : "Mercedes",
           extras : 5
        }
```

This looks completely unintuitive, but should be very fast and lightweight. How do you check whether the car has 4x4? Well, 4x4 is represented as `1000` (binary representation of `8`) so:

`if( !!(MyCar.extras & 8) ){ /* display a ✓ */ }`

so yeah, now we talk about hacks just by the look of this code. It's really simple but looks cryptic if you haven't played with bitwise operators before. To explain further: our car has the `extras` attribute set to `5`, which in binary is `0101` and we want to check if the left-most bit is set to `1`. Bitwise `AND` operation returns a number that has `1's` only where both operands have a `1`.

```
    0101  // 5
AND 1000  // 8
  = 0000
```

Now let's check for ABS, which is the 2nd bit from the left (`0100`, i.e. `4`).

```
var hasABS = !!( MyCar.extras & 4 ); // true
```

because

```
    0101  // 5
AND 0100  // 4
  = 0100
```

How to set the ESP to true? Simple:

```
MyCar.extras |= 3;  // now extras == 7
```

what has happened? a binary `OR` returns a number that has `1's` where either of its operands has a `1` bit.

`5 | 3` = `0101 | 0010` = `0111` = `7`;

Now to set the ABS to false you'd use

```
MyCar.extras ^= 4;
```

I'll leave the workings of binary `XOR` as an exercise to the reader, but I hope you get the gist of using bitmasks and "bit twiddling" now.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. The bit-twiddling is faster which is why it was  used. I guess it is used for tracking the filtered dimensions. Its nice to implement it like this. But the reader might not get the logic, which is why it seems hackish.